# Converting Vue 2 javascript to Vue 3 Typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am working on a vue 3(typescript) code project. I have one small piece of code which is of vue 2 javascript. Can anyone help me in converting the below code from vue 2 to vue 3 typescript:

```
<script>
import { QInput } from 'quasar'

import FormElement from '../FormElement'

export default {
  name: 'TextElement',
  extends: FormElement,
  components: { QInput }
}
```

Comment: what makes you think that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
 <template>
      <FormElement>
        <QInput v-model="value" />
      </FormElement>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    import { QInput } from 'quasar'
    
    import FormElement from '../FormElement'
    
    export default defineComponent({
      name: 'TextElement',
      extends: FormElement,
      components: { QInput }
    })
    </script>
```

Import Changes: Instead of using the import statement from Vue 2, we use import { defineComponent } from 'vue' for defining the component.

Template: The template content remains mostly the same, with the exception of the use of the v-model directive, which is now handled directly by the QInput component.

Export: The component is now defined using the defineComponent function, which takes an options object. The name property and the extends property remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works but failes when i write
<script setup lang="ts">
As i need this code purely in Vue 3 typescript

Error:
A module cannot have multiple default exports

Comment: well that code is pure vue3 ts, you are just trying to use composition api and the code above is in options api. Extending a component in composition api isnt really really done.